# Getting state of a text input when pressing enter key in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm taking my first steps with [React](https://reactjs.org) and I struggle with setting and getting states of an `input` element.

- The application shall render a simple `input` element *without* a submit button.
- When pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> the current value of the text field shall be written to the console.

So far I've added two event handlers for `onKeyUp` (checking if <kbd>Enter</kbd> was pressed) and another for `onChange` to output the text field's value.

This is my current code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Terminal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ""};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);    
  }

  handleKey(e) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      console.log("Enter key pressed");
      console.log(this.state.value);
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>My Prompt: > </span>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onKeyUp={this.handleKey} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }  
}    

ReactDOM.render(
  <Terminal />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> is recognized but logging to the console gives me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
    at handleKey (index.js:24)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 2 issues :

1. You bound `handleChange` but you forgot to bind `handleKey` in the constructor .

Better is to not use manual binding , but to use arrow function instead.

```
  handleKey = (e)  => {
   //....... ( See second issue )
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }
```

2. Second issue is how to know "enter" key is pressed . Use

   ```
    const keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode === 13) {
      // You code when "Enter" is pressed
    }
   ```

The demo below should work fine.

```js
    class Terminal extends React.Component {
      // no need explicit constructor !
      state = { value: '', cmds: [] };

      handleKey = e => {
        const keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
        if (keyCode === 13) {
          this.setState(({ cmds, value }) => ({
            value: '',
            cmds: [value, ...cmds]
          }));
        }
      };

      handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <div>
              <span>My Prompt: > </span>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.value}
                onKeyUp={this.handleKey}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            {this.state.cmds.map(cmd =>
              <div>
                {cmd}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Terminal />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: I was just about to comment this and agree arrow function is the better and cleaner way to go.

Comment: i would add that using an arrow function is not a black magic and it will help in this case only because it will use a lexical context for `this`, which is the `class` instance in this case.

Comment: @abdennour-toumi You're right. The first issue is now obvious to me. About the second issue... as far as I can see from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup the `key` event value should be preferred but is unimplemented in Firefox. So the solution you provided is mostly for legacy reaons?

Comment: @RobertStrauch. Yes it is polyfill , work in any browser. By the way, See the code snippet that I put, You will be happy ..  I complete the solution for you .

Answer (score 2):

just change thease:

```
 onChange={this.handleChange}
 onKeyUp={this.handleKey}
```

to

```
 onChange={this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)}
 onKeyUp={this.handleKey = this.handleKey.bind(this)}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `bind` the function to the context of the class.

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onKeyUp={this.handleKey.bind(this)} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: From what I can observe it seems to work in that case. I thought I had already bound it in the constructor. However it seems as if I missed binding the `handleKey` function.